# I get an error on MariaDB allways I start my App

Tags: docker, mariadb

I get this error message, if I start my Appication. But I don't understand the Problem. Can someone explain me, whats wrong? MariaDB runs on Docker Desktop for Windows.

```
2023-07-18 11:13:55 Version: '11.0.2-MariaDB-1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-07-18 11:44:52 2023-07-18  9:44:52 18 [ERROR] InnoDB: preallocating 131072 bytes for file ./firstdb/firsttable.ibd failed with error 2
2023-07-18 11:44:52 2023-07-18 09:44:52 0x7f50c40cd640  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file ./storage/innobase/fil/fil0fil.cc line 610
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: Failing assertion: fsize != os_offset_t(-1)
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: immediately after the mariadbd startup, there may be
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
2023-07-18 11:44:52 InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 230718  9:44:52 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
2023-07-18 11:44:52 This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
2023-07-18 11:44:52 or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
2023-07-18 11:44:52 or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
2023-07-18 11:44:52 diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Server version: 11.0.2-MariaDB-1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision: 0005f2f06c8e1aea4915887decad67885108a929
2023-07-18 11:44:52 key_buffer_size=134217728
2023-07-18 11:44:52 read_buffer_size=131072
2023-07-18 11:44:52 max_used_connections=11
2023-07-18 11:44:52 max_threads=153
2023-07-18 11:44:52 thread_count=11
2023-07-18 11:44:52 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 468023 K  bytes of memory
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Thread pointer: 0x7f50840456c8
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
2023-07-18 11:44:52 where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
2023-07-18 11:44:52 terribly wrong...
2023-07-18 11:44:52 stack_bottom = 0x7f50c40ccc78 thread_stack 0x49000
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Printing to addr2line failed
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x55df9923ea62]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(handle_fatal_signal+0x488)[0x55df98d11e28]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f50da752520]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_kill+0x12c)[0x7f50da7a6a7c]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(raise+0x16)[0x7f50da752476]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd3)[0x7f50da7387f3]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0x6970f3)[0x55df989260f3]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0x6a632a)[0x55df9893532a]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0x6a71e2)[0x55df989361e2]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0x6a9802)[0x55df98938802]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0x6aa1ee)[0x55df989391ee]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xefd975)[0x55df9918c975]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xefed61)[0x55df9918dd61]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xe7c3be)[0x55df9910b3be]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xebeb2e)[0x55df9914db2e]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xebf3f7)[0x55df9914e3f7]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xdf5461)[0x55df99084461]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xd86fce)[0x55df99015fce]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xd8ec75)[0x55df9901dc75]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xd9155d)[0x55df9902055d]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z17mysql_alter_tableP3THDPK25st_mysql_const_lex_stringS3_P22Table_specification_stP10TABLE_LISTP13Recreate_infoP10Alter_infojP8st_orderbb+0x4ede)[0x55df98b72f7e]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_ZN19Sql_cmd_alter_table7executeEP3THD+0x398)[0x55df98be29f8]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x4c5b)[0x55df98ab13fb]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x1e7)[0x55df98ab2637]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjb+0x14bd)[0x55df98ab4d7d]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z10do_commandP3THDb+0x138)[0x55df98ab69d8]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECTb+0x3bf)[0x55df98bdda3f]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(handle_one_connection+0x5d)[0x55df98bddd8d]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 mariadbd(+0xcb7066)[0x55df98f46066]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94b43)[0x7f50da7a4b43]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x44)[0x7f50da835bb4]
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Trying to get some variables.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Query (0x7f5084054140): alter table if exists verfahren add constraint indexName unique (name)
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Connection ID (thread ID): 18
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Status: NOT_KILLED
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on,not_null_range_scan=off,hash_join_cardinality=on
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
2023-07-18 11:44:52 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Writing a core file...
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Resource Limits:
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max locked memory         83968000             83968000             bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max pending signals       31802                31802                signals   
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max nice priority         0                    0                    
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Core pattern: core
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Kernel version: Linux version 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021
2023-07-18 11:44:52 
2023-07-18 11:44:52 Fatal signal 11 while backtracing
2023-07-18 11:44:53 2023-07-18 09:44:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2023-07-18 11:44:53 2023-07-18 09:44:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-07-18 11:44:53 2023-07-18 09:44:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18 09:44:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.0.2-MariaDB-1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 0005f2f06c8e1aea4915887decad67885108a929 as process 1
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: Aria engine: starting recovery
2023-07-18 11:44:54 recovered pages: 0% 14% 25% 36% 48% 59% 71% 84% 97% 100% (0.1 seconds); tables to flush: 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 (0.0 seconds); 
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: Aria engine: recovery done
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Warning] mariadbd: io_uring_queue_init() failed with ENOSYS: check seccomp filters, and the kernel version (newer than 5.1 required)
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Warning] InnoDB: liburing disabled: falling back to innodb_use_native_aio=OFF
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
2023-07-18 11:44:54 2023-07-18  9:44:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=16772438
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 241 pages from redo log.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 27005766; transaction id 2870
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230718  9:44:55
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/plugin'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] DDL_LOG: Crash recovery executed 1 entries
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/servers'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/db'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/proxies_priv'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/roles_mapping'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/global_priv'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_leap_second'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_name'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_transition_type'
2023-07-18 11:44:55 2023-07-18  9:44:55 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_transition'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/tables_priv'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/columns_priv'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/procs_priv'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/func'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/event'
2023-07-18 11:44:56 2023-07-18  9:44:56 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
2023-07-18 11:44:56 Version: '11.0.2-MariaDB-1:11.0.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

My Application creates some tables. Only a empty database is in MariaDB. After crash, all Tables are created. But an Index not exists.

Comment: [wsl bug, groan](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443)

Comment: Please post the code used to create the tables and indexes at startup, for analysis.  Not a SAMPLE.  Your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [WSL bug](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443) that hasn't been fixed since I lodged it.

The MariaDB Docker Official Image issue [#331](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/331) and corresponding MariaDB bugs [MDEV-31486](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31486), and [MDEV-24189](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24189) show the same behaviour, that a combination of file renames combined with fstat that are used in `ALTER TABLE` aren't implemented correctly in WSL.